# Binding Click event in KnockoutJS

Tags: knockout.js

I have a div which has a css binding according to the value of 'rowState' as follows which is working fine.

```
<div id="searchResult"  data-bind="css:{disabledRow: rowState === 2}">
```

Now, I need to bind the 'click' event to fire only if the rowState is not 2. I tried the following, but with no success.

```
<div id="searchResult"  data-bind="click:{$parent.rowClicked: rowState !== 2}, css:{disabledRow: rowState === 2}">
```

I do not want to use the if statement as the div has got lots of content which I would need to repeat. The only difference is to make the div not clickable if rowState is 2.
Could you please help me to sort this out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another solution could be:

```
data-bind="click: function() { rowState() !== 2 ? alert('click ok') : return; }, css:{disabledRow: rowState === 2}"
```

i took the fiddle from artem and changed it to work with my solution. You can find the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/x9CpD/15/

**Edit**

ah, I see: you actually want to prevend the event binding if rowState != 2. I think you can only do this with a custom BindingHandler

Comment: I tried this solution. It is working fine with the alert function. But, when I replace alert('click ok') with $parent.rowClicked, it is not working.

Comment: hm...strange behaviour, here is another fiddle, that works. tried with $root. and with $parent http://jsfiddle.net/x9CpD/20/

Answer (score 0):

You could add checking `rowState`'s value to the click event handler:

```
self.rowClicked = function(data) {
    if (data.rowState() != 2) {
        return false;
    }

    console.log("Clicked");
    // Do work
}
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/x9CpD/1/

Comment: Thanks for the response. But, this solution will fire the event even if it is not required. Is there a way not to fire the event when rowState=2?

Comment: I don't see the problem with the event firing anyway.